# Select the next element in a list on click using Jquery

Tags: jquery, list

In a list of elements, I want to be able to show the next hidden one after a button is clicked. But with my present code I can only do it once..

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>

$("ul li").next().hide();
$("button").click(function(){
    $("ul li").next().slice(0,1).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:visible` selector to find all the `li` elements that are currently not hidden, then take the last element of that array, find its `next` sibling and make that (and more up to the required number of elements) visible:

```js
$("ul li").next().hide();
$("button").click(function() {
  let num = parseInt($('#num').val()) || 1;
  let first = $("ul li:visible").slice(-1).next();
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    first.fadeIn();
    first = first.next();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="num">Extra Elements</label>
<input id="num" type="text" />
<button>Show</button>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How could I do the same for the next 4 items?

Comment: @FernandoSouza I'm not sure what you mean? If you keep pressing the button, more elements become visible. Is that not what you want?

Comment: I mean, make the next 4 elements show instead of just one.

Comment: So, when you press the button the first time, 2-5 would show and then the second time 6 and 7 would show?

Comment: When I press the first time it would show from 2~5, second time 6~9.

Comment: @FernandoSouza see my edit. It shows how to allow for a different number of elements to show for each button press.